# Does every class in the design model have to be present in the domain model?

Tags: uml

I have doubt regarding design model.Does every class in the design model have to be present in the domain model?

Comment: Please be more specific. What language? More details please.

Answer (score 0):

Object modeling is best done as an iterative process, so start with whatever (simple) design you think meets your current requirements and build upon it as you learn more about your domain.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not well explained even if the subject is important.
UML is an object approach like Java codding while domain modelling is related to databases structure. UML is not therefore the same as domain modelling.

Having said that JD5 and later allows ORM annotations in the code. It means that at object level you can also think about databases using Hibernate annotations directly in your java code. EclipseUML is lived synchronized with the Java code but also with ORM annotations. It means that all ORM annotations written in the code are updated in the class diagram as well as in the model and each class diagram annotations change is updated in the code.

It means that UML and domain modelling are now unified using standard ORM annotation.